# Is there a way to indicate NP^{\prod_i^P} or coNP^{\prod_i^P} like in polynomial hierarchy?

Tags: computation, complexity

In know that in polynomial hierarchy

[image]

I was wondering if there exists a way (and if it does make sense) to indicate [image: $NP^{\prod_i^P}$] or [image: $coNP^{\prod_i^P}$].

Comment: What does this have to do with philosophy?

Comment: @causative See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_hierarchy